# Why is the . needed for adding suffixes to the 'auto-mode-alist?

Tags: major-mode, list

In 
https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoModeAlist
one needs to use this command in order to add .py for python-mode `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.py\\'" . python-mode))`
Why do we need the `.` between `'"\\.py\\'"` and the `python-mode` ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is lisp syntax for a *dotted pair*:

```
(cons 'a 'b) -> (a . b)
```

Here's a [link](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Dotted-Pair-Notation.html#Dotted-Pair-Notation).

Briefly, dotted pairs are the fundamental building blocks for lists: lists are special dotted pairs, defined recursively. Most of the time, you work with lists so the dotted pairs are hidden in the background, but once in a while (as in this case), they poke through.

Answer (score 3):

That's because [`auto-mode-alist`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Auto-Major-Mode.html) is an ["association list"](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Association-Lists.html) (a [list](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Lists.html) of [pairs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Dotted-Pair-Notation.html)).